# NVSUMSS map mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, healpy

I'm trying to reproduce Fig 3 of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.04739, but I'm getting the given image
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

nside = 64
npix = hp.nside2npix(nside)

mp1 = pd.read_table('NVSStest.text', delim_whitespace = True, error_bad_lines=False, usecols = [i for i in range(7)])
mp1 = mp1.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
mp1 = mp1.dropna()

RA_H1 = np.array(mp1['1'], dtype = np.float64)  
RA_M1 = np.array(mp1['2'], dtype = np.float64)
RA_S1 = np.array(mp1['3'], dtype = np.float64)

DEC_H1 = np.array(mp1['4'], dtype = np.float64)
DEC_M1 = np.array(mp1['5'], dtype = np.float64)
DEC_S1 = np.array(mp1['6'], dtype = np.float64)

RA1 = np.zeros(len(RA_H1), dtype = np.float64)
DEC1 = np.zeros(len(RA_H1), dtype = np.float64)
phi1 = np.zeros(len(RA_H1), dtype = np.float64)
theta1 = np.zeros(len(RA_H1), dtype = np.float64)
count1 = np.zeros(len(RA_H1), dtype = np.float64)

fs1 = np.array(mp1['7'], dtype = np.float64)

for i in range (len(RA_H1)):
    RA1[i] = 15*(RA_H1[i] + RA_M1[i]/60 + RA_S1[i]/3600)
    phi1[i] = RA1[i]*np.pi/180
    
for i in range (len(RA_H1)):
    DEC1[i] = (DEC_H1[i] + DEC_M1[i]/60 + DEC_S1[i]/3600)
    theta1[i] = (90 - DEC1[i])*np.pi/180
    
indices1 = hp.ang2pix(nside, theta1, phi1)

ind1 = np.zeros(len(RA_H1), dtype = np.float64)

ind1 = sorted(indices1)

for i in range(len(ind1)):
    if(fs1[i]>15):
        for j in range(i-1000, i):
            if(ind1[i] == ind1[j] and fs1[i]>15):
                count1[ind1[i]] += 1
                break

mp2 = pd.read_table('sumsstest.txt', delim_whitespace = True, error_bad_lines=False, usecols = [i for i in range(11)])
mp2 = mp2.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
mp2 = mp2.dropna()

RA_H2 = np.array(mp2['1'], dtype = np.float64)  
RA_M2 = np.array(mp2['2'], dtype = np.float64)
RA_S2 = np.array(mp2['3'], dtype = np.float64)

DEC_H2 = np.array(mp2['4'], dtype = np.float64)
DEC_M2 = np.array(mp2['5'], dtype = np.float64)
DEC_S2 = np.array(mp2['6'], dtype = np.float64)

RA2 = np.zeros(len(RA_H2), dtype = np.float64)
DEC2 = np.zeros(len(RA_H2), dtype = np.float64)
phi2 = np.zeros(len(RA_H2), dtype = np.float64)
theta2 = np.zeros(len(RA_H2), dtype = np.float64)
count2 = np.zeros(len(RA_H2), dtype = np.float64)

fs2 = np.array(mp2['9'], dtype = np.float64)

for i in range(len(fs2)):
    fs2[i] = fs2[i]*(843/1400)**0.81

for i in range (len(RA_H2)):
    RA2[i] = 15*(RA_H2[i] + RA_M2[i]/60 + RA_S2[i]/3600)
    phi2[i] = RA2[i]*np.pi/180
    
for i in range (len(RA_H2)):
    DEC2[i] = (DEC_H2[i] + DEC_M2[i]/60 + DEC_S2[i]/3600)
    theta2[i] = (90 - DEC2[i])*np.pi/180
    
indices2 = hp.ang2pix(nside, theta2, phi2)

ind2 = np.zeros(len(RA_H2), dtype = np.float64)

ind2 = sorted(indices2)

for i in range(len(ind2)):
    if(fs2[i]>15):
        for j in range(i-1000, i):
            if(ind2[i] == ind2[j] and fs2[i]>15):
                count2[ind2[i]] += 1
                break
hpxmap1 = np.zeros(npix, dtype=np.float64)
for i in range(len(ind1)):
  hpxmap1[ind1[i]] = np.log10(1 + count1[ind1[i]])
  
for i in range(len(ind2)):
  hpxmap1[ind2[i]] = np.log10(1 + count2[ind2[i]])

hp.mollview(hpxmap1, title="Mollview image RING", norm = "hist", cmap = cm.jet)
        
plt.show()
```

The data I used are taken from these sites:

https://www.cv.nrao.edu/cgi-bin/NVSSlist.pl

http://www.astrop.physics.usyd.edu.au/sumsscat/update

What changes can I make in the code to get the desired result?

Comment: I haven't checked your code in detail yet, I recommend you take a look at this tutorial on how to map data to a healpix map: https://gist.github.com/zonca/680c68c3d60697eb0cb669cf1b41c324

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have looked into that tutorial beforehand, the issue I am facing is that the result I got is not matching with the result given in the paper.

Comment: I would use astropy or pyephem to do coordinate conversion. Try to double check coordinate conversion before plotting map